# Figuring out correct DateTime format in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to figure out how to get the `'when'` variable in the right datetime format.

Its value is in: ***MM/yyyy*** format.

```
       rt.Add(new RoadTrip()
         {
           Id = int.Parse(rec[0]),
           Where = rec[1],
           How = int.Parse(rec[2]),
           When = DateTime.Parse(rec[3]),
           WithWhat = rec[4]                              
         });
```

Comment: What's the value of `rec[3]`?  What error or problem are you seeing?  You may need to look at using `DateTime.ParseExact` so you can specify the exact format you want to parse from.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
When = DateTime.ParseExact(rec[3], "MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
```

For a value of "10/2015" you will get a `DateTime` object with the value "10/1/2015 12;00:00 AM".  Note that this will also throw a `FormatException` if the value does not match the format.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify the format of the string that you want to parse to a date.

In your case it will probably use something like:

```
When = DateTime.ParseExact(rec[3], "MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```